# Split menu into 3 sections [left, center & right] ALMOST Working

Tags: css, menu

http://jsfiddle.net/DWLZG/

I have a menu which i've split into 3 different parts.
It's working, however, when scaling the browser to smaller size, the links positioned in the center do not scale adequately.

If you try to resize the browser to smaller, you can see that the RIGHT-most and CENTER links collide together way before the links on the LEFT (there is a big gap between LEFT and CENTER).
If i set the center div css to "absolute/left:50%" than everything scales nicely but however, i then have a new problem of the CENTER links overlapping each other.

In the HTML i CAN-NOT assign any class'es.

How could i achieve adequate scalability?

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li id="left"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li id="left"><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
<li id="center"><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
<li id="center"><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
<li id="center"><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
<li id="right"><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
ul#menu {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ff0000;
}
li {
    display:inline;    
}

#left {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    float: left;       
}
#center {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
    /*position: absolute;
    left: 50%;*/   
}
#right {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

- First remove `left` declaration for center elements:

  ```
  #center {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    /*position: relative;
    left: 25%; Remove this*/
  }
  ```
- Then center your elements with this on the parent:

  ```
  ul#menu {
   text-align:center;
  }
  ```

Check the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DWLZG/2/)**

*Note --* <sub>You can't use multiple ID. ID must be unique in the document your markup is invalid</sub>

Comment: Thumbs Up! Works beautiful! Thanks very much!
@AlienArrays; I can see that working but its somewhat messy. Thanks aswell.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/DWLZG/1/

I added this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
    #right, #center { 
        float: left;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

It works just about perfectly I think. You may want to change 380 to like 420 or so. Whatever you like.